# How can I add a extra li element to "create" button in sites in aem

Tags: html, button, adobe, aem, jcr

I having been trying to add a custom li tag to create button in sites in AEM.
I could not find the html page to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is documented here:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/extending-aem/customizing-consoles-touch.html

BUT: This is a pretty complicated and advanced topic - as AEM is a pretty complex software, and its internals are not always logical. Additionally you should be a very experienced AEM developer. Otherwise you might create bugs inside the product, make it slow - or simply your extensions will fail to make use of existing AEM functionality.